# F# memory management

Tags: arrays, memory-management, reference, f#

In F# when you pass an Array in a loop (recursive function calling itself) is the Array put on the stack (adding memory consumption) each loop? How does it work with lists or referenced objects when looping them? Could you minimize memory consumption somehow, maybe by using ref (references)?

Comment: This is the sort of question that can be trivially answered yourself by writing such a function.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I needed to know since I don't know how to debug memory consumption of my f# programs and I know many functions are optimized by the compiler. So I wondered what really happened when a function with a list/array/ref as argument continuously looped. At least it's now easily found on stack overflow if someone needs to know :)

Comment: You ncan always use task manager

Comment: That's true, don't know why I didn't think about that. Will try that out. Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting that the array will always be on the heap (arrays are not value objects in .NET), the reference to the array may be (depending on context details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are reference types, so you're not copying or constructing arrays when you pass them as arguments. If you pass around arrays in a recursive function, you're not incurring space overhead.

For example:

```
let rec loop a i =
  if 0 <= i && i < Array.length a then 
    loop a (a.[i])
  else
    a.[i]
```

This function jumps around the array until it finds a value that is not an index of the array. Assuming tail-call optimization, it has no space-overhead, ie., it allocates nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you write tail-recursive functions, then F# will do tail-call-optimization, such that the stack does not grow in each recursive call.

If you have a function that is not tail-recursive, you can use something called continuation passing style and use the heap instead of the stack for accumulating intermediate values.

Comment: So if the function is not tail recursive but can be stopped by for example stopping the application through another thread, the optimization that can be made is to allocate on the heap and use a continuation passing style (which I'll read more about)? Would that mean that the memory being used by the application is growing as the pointers to the dynamically allocated memory is added to another in memory?

Comment: Basically if you can do tail-call-optimization (because the value is never used as the function is tail-recursive), the compiler will do so. If that is not possible, the compiler would not be able to do so. And CPS is a way how to "force" tail-recursion. This forcing, though simply moves the memory from stack to heap.

And yes, the memory grows, because you are building up a state that is needed at some later point. Until you compute the final result at which point, the data is GCed

Answer (score 1):

As long as your function is tail recursive you don't have to worry. This simply means the last thing your function does is call itself. Example:

```
let rec fact x =
    if x < 1 then 1
    else x * fact (x - 1)
```

This function multiply's by x after fact (x - 1) so its NOT tail recursive.

Comment: -1 ... This isn't tail recursive at all. After fact(x-1), its return value has to be multiplied by x which makes tail recursion impossible. A tail recursive factorial function has to use some kind of accumulation value.

Comment: My bad. Thats an example of a function thats NOT tail recursive. Thanks for the headsup. Fixed